# Why does the toString() method work different when written as a separate statement?

Tags: javascript

The argument passed in the toString() method is supposed to be the base upon which the  Number is changed to it's equivalent string.
For example, 6.toString(2) is supposed to give its binary i.e. 110.

But when I use the following code:

```
var x = 6;
x.toString(2);
console.log(x);
```

It outputs 6.

But when I use:

```
var x = 6;
console.log(x.toString(2));
```

It outputs 110.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not changing the value of x in the first case try the following code snippet

```js
var x = 6;
x.toString(2);
console.log(x);

x = x.toString(2);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Oops! I see! That was a very stupid question to ask. Thanks!